# how do I fix this raycast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

am trying to shoot a raycast from the center of the screen to whatever is in front of It, and I have a working raycast from another script that I put into this one, but no matter what I try, it doesnt work

this is the code for the raycast

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Interact : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float raycastDistance = 100.0f;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            Debug.Log("it works");
            RaycastHit hit;

            
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, raycastDistance))
            {
                
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("InteractableObject"))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Raycast sent");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried everything, nothing works. please help

Comment: If your raycast hits something that's *not* an InteractableObject, then you won't see anything happening.  Most likely, your ray cast is hitting the camera.  Add an ```else``` to that inner ```if``` and print the name of the thing that gets hit.

Comment: are you sure the transform.position is the middle of the screen and "forward" is trhe right angle?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem is on your RayCast Parameter.

Let try to use Vector3.forward Instead of TransformDirection(Vector3.forward)

```
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.forward, out hit, raycastDistance))
```

Comment: still isn't working for some reason

Answer (score 0):

How about your debug message is it show correctly?
Can you try to use DrawRay to see visual of Raycast

```
void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector3.forward);
}
```

After compile this script it will show ray on unity editor

Comment: still doesn't work, I have no idea what i've done wrong, the same raycast code ive used here works in one of my other scripts, yet for some reason, it refuses to work here. I need help

Comment: yeah it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that it would be a problem is Collider. Make sure that object that you want to detect has collider attached on.

In my opinion, script didn't wrong but it's other component in unity editor that it would missing so check you collider then it's supposed to work

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that:

- this `Interact` component is on the exact same object as your `Camera` component?
- the object's `transform.forward`is pointing in the same sirection as your camera is.
- there is a collider on the interactible object.
- the interactible object has the correct layer set. This layer needs to be set on the object that has the collider you expect to hit.
- The layer name in your code matches exactly with the layer name in Unity. This includes spaces and is case sensitive.
- the interactible object is withing the raycast distance.
- there are no colliders obstructing the raycast.

You should definitely draw this ray in the scene either using
[Debug.DrawRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html) or [Gizmos.DrawRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawRay.html) to ensure it is casting the ray where you need it to.